# How to reload localStorage saved aws-amplify auth?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am successfully using AWS Amplify and AWS Cognito for my spa authorization.
The only issue is that when I refresh the page, the auth seems to be lost, even if I see amplify and cognito items in LocalStorage.

This is my configuration section:

```
Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {
    oauth: {
      domain: 'xxxxx.auth.eu-west-1.amazoncognito.com',
      scope: ['phone', 'email', 'profile', 'openid'],
      responseType: 'code',
      oauth.redirectSignIn: 'http://localhost:3000/',
      oauth.redirectSignOut: 'http://localhost:3000/',
    },
    region: process.env.REACT_APP_REGION,
    userPoolId: process.env.REACT_APP_USER_POOL_ID,
    userPoolWebClientId: process.env.REACT_APP_USER_POOL_WEB_CLIENT_ID,
    storage: localStorage,
  },
});
```

In practice, I don't know how to ask amplify to use localStorage when user is authenticated and app restarts (page reload).
Possibly I should use Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser(), but I suppose I can't call it instead of Auth.configure()...

Comment: Your code snippet isn't valid javascript... you have property assignment right in the middle of your object declaration. You are also using a global `localStorage`, pass `window.localStorage` instead. Or remove it because it is the default anyway. In any case calling currentAuthenticatedUser should reload the user from storage.

Comment: @AndrewGillis: Yes. Just corrected my code, the error was due to a quick copy'n'paste from my code in order to simplify the question... About localStorage, it works without `window.` too, don't know why... However `calling currentAuthenticatedUser` is **the correct answer**... I came to it too myself, yesterday. I was thinking to answer my queston myself. If you want to answer, I'll accept it...

Comment: Yeah I understand that you can pass `localStorage`, however it isn't declared in scope and is attached to the window object so you should be referencing it explicitly. Also, the code is still incorrect. remove `oauth.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch the user from storage by calling `Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()`.

It isn't properly documented but you can [refer to the implementation](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/blob/a84978d61960907957699882bc16724287dd522f/packages/auth/src/Auth.ts#L1339) to see the behavior (amplify team must believe in self-documenting code).